Link from outside website or another page to a text widget title
I have a conference theme running on Wordpress, in the main page which is named as FrontPage, I need to add a link in the menu bar to one of the text widgets on the page.
I do not know how to target a text widget on the page.
Currently, I have done it by adding a  element to the start of the widget text but the drawback is that after navigation to it, the title is hidden upwards.

Do you have a fixed header, so that when you scroll down your header stays at the top of the page?
